# How can :hover inherit the link color by default

Tags: html, css

I  want every :hover to automatically inherit the color defined for respective `a` element, if not defined specifically. `color:inherit;` doesnt seem to do it, any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: a,a:hover { color: whatever } is the only way

Comment: I don't understand, it should inherit it by default. The color stays the same on hover here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3QYnd/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`color: inherit` tells the `a` element to inherit the color from its parent, not its "normal" or "generic" state.

Since `:hover` is simply a state of the `a` element, if you don't specify a color for `a:hover` then it will use whatever color that was already declared for it in, for example, an `a` rule. So simply don't specify a color. If there's a different value already set and you want to override it, the only way is to set the same color as given in the `a` rule in the original stylesheet.